# Repository is not saving data onError method, while saving onWrite method of Listener

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a simple listener with 3 methods. and a repository with autowired on that. While saving an object from afterWrite it works nicely. but when saving item from onError methods no exception occurs, however it is not saving any data. Thankful for suggestions.

public class WriteListener implements ItemWriteListener{

```
public void beforeWrite(List items) {
    System.out.println("Going to write following items: "+ items.toString());
}

public void onWriteError(Exception exception, List items) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred when writing items!");

     testRepository.save(items.get(0)); //not working
}
public void afterWrite(List items) {
    testRepository.save(items.get(0)); //not nicely and save data
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited information provided, most likely the cause is the exception itself. The exception would have marked current transaction as dirty thus spring would have rolled it back.

If you still want to store data in your listener despite existing exception, use it in a separate transaction context. Simplest way for that would be to use @Async annotation on your listener and marking it Transactional explicitly to ensure it initiate a new transaction. Check out [Spring Event](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) which covers this topic in little bit more depth.

Comment: That's correct, from the javadoc of `ItemWriteListener#onWriteError`: "Will be called inside a transaction, but the transaction will normally be rolled back". So if items should be saved in this method, a new transaction should used.